# expected an indented block python choregraphe

Tags: python

Hi I am new in Python and this is an error that many people have but I could'nt be helped by any other thread. The code is straight from this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f_zzxwOvRWA) .
And it  posts:[ERROR] behavior.box :FMBox::createPythonModule:0 _Behavior__lastUploadedChoregrapheBehaviorbehavior_1291762048__root__headnod_1: User class evaluation failed with the error:

('expected an indented block', ('', 19, 11, 'motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,1.0],times,True)\n'))

Thank you in advance

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
def __init__(self):
    GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

def onLoad(self):
    #put initialization code here
    pass

def onUnload(self):
    pass

def onInput_onStart(self):
    motionProxy=ALProxy("ALMotion")
    names = ['HeadYaw','HeadPitch']
times = [[0.5],[0.5]]
motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,0.0],times,True)

for i in range(3):
motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,1.0],times,True)
motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,-1.0],times,True)

motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,0.0],times,True)

self.onStopped()

def onInput_onStop(self):
    self.onUnload() #it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped
    self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```

Comment: Indent your `for` loop.  Cut and paste often screws-up indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error says that your code is incorrectly indented.
For python you need to indent each block of code, like `class` body, `for` loop body, etc:

```
class MyClass(GeneratedClass):
    def __init__(self):
        GeneratedClass.__init__(self)

    def onLoad(self):
        #put initialization code here
        pass

    def onUnload(self):
        pass

    def onInput_onStart(self):
        motionProxy=ALProxy("ALMotion")
        names = ['HeadYaw','HeadPitch']

        times = [[0.5],[0.5]]
        motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,0.0],times,True)

        for i in range(3):
            motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,1.0],times,True)
            motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,-1.0],times,True)

        motionProxy.angleInterpolation(names,[0.0,0.0],times,True)

        self.onStopped()

    def onInput_onStop(self):
        self.onUnload() #it is recommended to reuse the clean-up as the box is stopped
        self.onStopped() #activate the output of the box
```

Check this chapter from Dive Into Python - [Indenting Code](http://www.diveintopython.net/getting_to_know_python/indenting_code.html). Also just a note that code above is not complete, it is a part of something bigger, so you anyway can't just use this code alone to do something.